I'm trying to upgrade my tomcat from 7 to tomcat 10 with open jdk 14. My application is a basic servlet application and not using any framework
I've included all the jars which are necessary for jakarta and compiled my files with latest jars. Still getting classcastexception. unable to load dispatcher servlet.
trying to upgrade from tomcat 7 to tomcat 10
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Marking servlet [LoginServlet] as unavailable
09-Apr-2024 15:46:00.830 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Allocate exception for servlet [LoginServlet]
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.vno.vendorportal.controllers.LoginServlet cannot be cast to class jakarta.servlet.Servlet (com.vno.vendorportal.controllers.LoginServlet is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @36f1046f; jakarta.servlet.Servlet is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @4e515669)
